# React remove click event using jQuery

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have a  tag that has onClick property. How can I remove the event from the tag using jQuery? is that even possible?

Comment: please don't mix jQuery and react as jQuery makes changes directly to the dom while react re renders when the dom's changed and they will shout at each other and you will not end up well. Can't you just remove the onClick from the react code instead? I think you will get better of that way tbh.

Comment: @LucasReppeWelander. I agree with you it is not even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. You can add a new event and then stop propagation but it's hacky. jQuery cannot remove events it does not own.

if the component composes props, you can override it or add `onClickCapture={e => e.stopPropagation()}`

eg if your component allows you to pass props, even if onClick is after the prop spread, you can still do it via the capture phase of the event which fires before the handler:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

  handleClick(e){
    console.info(e)
  }

  render(){
    return <button {...this.props} onClick={this.handleClick}>click me</button>
  }
}

const app = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(<Foo onClickCapture={e => e.stopPropagation()} />, app)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tdbs7h05/

Otherwise, you can read the source code and "hack it" by changing the prototype of the component. For example:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

  handleClick(e){
    console.info(e)
  }

  render(){
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click me</button>
  }
}

const app = document.getElementById('app')
Foo.prototype.handleClick = (e) => e.preventDefault() || e.stopPropagation()
ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, app)
```

Comment: Yes I have to admit it is hacky and not recommended. If it is not possible then I will just disable it on the component level and not using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Oh the answer above gave me idea so instead of overriding the component prop, override the event instead.

```
<button onClick={this.props.handleClick}>click me</button>

var elem = $('.yourbutton');
elem.click(() => { return false });
```